# Why can't I select objects in Figma?

Tags: figma

Many times it appears impossible to select an object by clicking on it in the main screen, even though it is not locked. What can cause the issue?

Comment: Perhaps it's a permissions issue? There's not enough detail for us to really help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to move an arrow with no tail. It is extremely difficult to select. In fact, the only way is to click exactly at the intersection of the 2 head bars.

Comment: This looks like some kind of bug. Add a screenshot to the post, I think that should clarify what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot select more than one object, you may be in **view mode**.
Most likely, you need access to edit or you need to log in to Figma under your name.

Here you can read more about it

https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040318013-Present-designs-and-prototypes

I hope this helped you, if not, write to me.

Comment: He only wants to select one object. I can reproduce. I open a figma diagram and clicking doesn't select anything. When I click and drag, the diagram moves around as expected.

Comment: The upper left side of the page looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/1AgPWnT.png. I can't see the sidebar, nor the layers tree Pressing `CTRL+Shift+\` (as suggested here: https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039831974-View-layers-and-pages-in-the-left-sidebar) does nothing.

Comment: Right-clicking on the diagram shows no context menu (trying to follow instructions from here: https://forum.figma.com/t/right-side-bar-disappeared/20141), and right-clicking higher, on the title bar (not the browser title bar, but the diagram title bar) shows the browser's context menu ("back", "reload", "save as", "print", "cast", etc.)